# How do I process a query parameter using NestJS?

Tags: typescript, rest, nestjs

The subject line is pretty much it.

I have a NestJS-based REST API server.  I want to process a query parameter like so:

```
http://localhost:3000/todos?complete=false
```

I can't seem to work out how to have the controller process that.

right now I have:

```
  @Get()
  async getTodos(@Query('complete') isComplete: boolean) {
    const todosEntities = await this.todosService.getTodosWithComlete(isComplete);
    const todos = classToPlain(todosEntities);
    return todos;
  }
```

but that always returns the completed todos, not the ones where complete = false.

Here's the call to `getTodosWithComlete`:

```
  async getTodosWithComplete(isComplete?: boolean): Promise<Todo[]> {
    return this.todosRepository.find({
      complete: isComplete,
      isDeleted: false,
    });
  }
```

How do I return the proper `todos` based on a query parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default all query parameters is string.
If you want to have a boolean injected in your function getTodos you can use pipe classes to transform your parameters.
According to https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes, there are already some built in pipes in NestJS, one of them is called ParseBoolPipe

So need to inject it in the Query decorator as second argument

```
@Get()
  async getTodos(@Query('complete', ParseBoolPipe) isComplete: boolean) {
    const todosEntities = await this.todosService.getTodosWithComlete(isComplete);
    const todos = classToPlain(todosEntities);
    return todos;
 }
```

Comment: Oh, that is so much better.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Well, interesting, the parameter as used above always  returns true, no matter what is passed in the URL.

Comment: Since version 7, there are implicit param conversion, https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide#implicit-type-conversion-validationpipe
But I never tested that.